# How to debug and solve an OS X 10.8 kernel panic which appears quite often, sometimes twice a day?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, kernel-panic

Suddenly my Mac started to have kernel panics, about 1-2 a day.

I am running latest OS X 10.8.2 on a 15-inch, Early 2011 MacBook Pro 8GB RAM with Graphics  AMD Radeon HD 6750M 1024 MB, Intel SSD + HD.

I mention I did no recent hardware

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  274133 sec
Anonymous UUID:                    0539B83C-471F-8386-735D-58B2076B237F

Tue Nov  6 07:10:56 2012
panic(cpu 5 caller 0xffffff802aab7bd5): Kernel trap at 0xffffff802aa874b3, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000020, CR3: 0x000000002d297000, CR4: 0x00000000000606e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000020, RBX: 0xffffff8031e12980, RCX: 0x0000000000000020, RDX: 0x00000000000018e9
RSP: 0xffffff811ab33dc0, RBP: 0xffffff811ab33de0, RSI: 0x000000002245cdc0, RDI: 0xffffff802ea02bc0
R8:  0x0000000000000001, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0xffffff802b0bdc25, R11: 0x00000000ffffff01
R12: 0x000000000001978f, R13: 0x0000000000000045, R14: 0xffffff802ea02bc0, R15: 0xffffff802d9f6000
RFL: 0x0000000000010203, RIP: 0xffffff802aa874b3, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000020, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x5

Backtrace (CPU 5), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff811ab33a60 : 0xffffff802aa1d626 
0xffffff811ab33ad0 : 0xffffff802aab7bd5 
0xffffff811ab33ca0 : 0xffffff802aace4ed 
0xffffff811ab33cc0 : 0xffffff802aa874b3 
0xffffff811ab33de0 : 0xffffff802aa7e01f 
0xffffff811ab33f70 : 0xffffff802aa7ecf2 
0xffffff811ab33fb0 : 0xffffff802aab26b7 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
12C60

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0: Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 69A5853F-375A-3EF4-9247-478FD0247333
Kernel slide:     0x000000002a800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff802aa00000
System model name: MacBookPro8,2 (Mac-94245A3940C91C80)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 75031661011235
last loaded kext at 580756463496: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs   1.8 (addr 0xffffff7facd64000, size 229376)
last unloaded kext at 241791295869: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   5.2.5 (addr 0xffffff7fab3c1000, size 65536)
loaded kexts:
com.citrix.driver.net6im    1.1.9
com.deterministicnetworks.driver.dne    1.0.18
com.deterministicnetworks.driver.dniregistry    1.0.7
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 1.8
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.69
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport  4.0.9f33
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.10
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   8.0.0
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.2.11
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.2d0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.33
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.0
com.apple.AMDRadeonAccelerator  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.2.11
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    8.0.0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.2d6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  235.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 235.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  320.15
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 34
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.2.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.2.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.2.5b3
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.6
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   602.15.22
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   5.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 196.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   4.0.39
com.apple.security.quarantine   2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   196.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.6
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.9fc10
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   86.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.0.9f33
com.apple.iokit.AppleBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport 4.0.9f33
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.2.0d16
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.10d0
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily 19.0.26
com.apple.kext.AMD6000Controller    8.0.0
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.2.11
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.5
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.4d2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 235.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.2b1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   500.15
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 5.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.8.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  220
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 344
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.21
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro8,2, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.3 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.69f3
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 512 MB
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6750M, AMD Radeon HD 6750M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D534F344758334D314131333333433920
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D534F344758334D314131333333433920
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.81.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.9f33 10885, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: INTEL SSDSC2CT180A3, 180.05 GB
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK7559GSXF, 750.16 GB
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8509, 0xfa200000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0252, 0xfa120000 / 5
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x821a, 0xfa113000 / 8
```

Comment: What software is running at the time of the panic?

Comment: Nothing in particular, I found no pattern regarding what I was running, usually Chrome, Safari, Office 2011, Skype, sometimes IntelliJ IDEA, iTerm2,...

Comment: Use Terminal to run the command shown at http://pastebin.com/PjBZgSba then restart the Mac. You'll get verbose boot, verbose shut down and more importantly: the next .panic file will show more information in the backtrace.

Comment: And to avoid a possible broken link in the future the command is: sudo nvram boot-args="-v keepsyms=y"

Comment: Download etrecheck.  Click on the download link at the bottom of the screen.
http://etrecheck.com  export file. post back here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd get rid of those Citrix kexts, first of all:

```
com.citrix.driver.net6im    1.1.9
com.deterministicnetworks.driver.dne    1.0.18
com.deterministicnetworks.driver.dniregistry    1.0.7
```

A quick Google shows them to be linked with kernal panics.

Comment: Posted this answer before I realised how old this question was. Don't know why it was top of the list.

Comment: That’s not a problem, answering old questions is encouraged. I think this answer is very plausible, +1

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, these frequent kernel panics can result from bad memory, either the chips or their slots.

I suggest you take out one of the two memory modules, test it, change out the memory module with the one you took out, test it, then repeat for the second slot. Essentially, test every combination of modules and slots to try and see if there is a problem caused by faulty memory.

Comment: You can also test memory without physically removing it. Run https://github.com/Vavius/memtest from single user mode!